# If conditioning a small list in Python

Tags: python

I want to use if condition for elements of the given list:

```
list = ['apple','banana','carrot']

for i in list:
    if i == 'apple' or 'banana': ##Here is problem!
        print i, 'pass'
```

The result is wrong:

```
apple pass
banana pass
carrot pass
```

It should be:

```
apple pass
banana pass
```

**The no of elements to be tested in my problem are large, so looking for better way of handling it.**

Comment: `if i == 'apple' or i == 'banana':`, think I saw these type of questions 100 times..

Comment: @AvinashRaj I want shortened form of it when the elements tobe tested are large

Comment: `if i in ['apple', 'banana', 'something else', '...']` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in line -

```
if i == 'apple' or 'banana':
```

You are checking if `i == 'apple'` or if `'banana'` is true. All strings are true, so if you do -

```
if 'banana':
```

It will always evaluate to true, and hence you are getting the issue of all values getting printed.

You need to do -

```
if i == 'apple' or i == 'banana':
```

Or you can also do -

```
if i in ['apple','banana']:
```